# Is there a REST API or any other way to get all branches for all repositories in VSTS?

Tags: git, azure-devops, azure-devops-rest-api

I would like to have the list of all branches of all repositories under my VSTS account.
I could find `https://{account}.visualstudio.com/DefaultCollection/_apis/git/repositories?api-version=1.0`. But, this does not list all branches under my repository, it only lists default branch.

I have code in C#,

```
var personalaccesstoken = "TOKEN";

using (HttpClient client = new HttpClient())
{
    client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(
    new System.Net.Http.Headers.MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/json"));

    client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Authorization = new AuthenticationHeaderValue("Basic",
    Convert.ToBase64String(
        System.Text.ASCIIEncoding.ASCII.GetBytes(
            string.Format("{0}:{1}", "", personalaccesstoken))));

using (HttpResponseMessage response = client.GetAsync(
            "https://{account}.visualstudio.com/DefaultCollection/_apis/git/repositories?api-version=1.0").Result)
{
    response.EnsureSuccessStatusCode();
    string responseBody = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
    Console.WriteLine(responseBody);
}
Console.ReadLine();
```

Can anyone point towards the REST API or tell me a way to get all the branches under a repository?

Comment: Do you want to get all branches of a given repo? The REST API list refs can return all the branches and tags for a given git repo.

Comment: Not for a given repo, I need branch information for all repos.

Comment: I added the way to get all the branches of the git repos in my answer, you can have a try.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use two loops to get all the branches for all git repositories in your VSTS account. Detail steps as below:

#### 1. [Get all the projects](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/vsts/core/projects/list?view=vsts-rest-4.1) in your VSTS account

```
GET https://{account}.visualstudio.com/_apis/projects?api-version=4.1-preview.1
```

In the response will return all the projects in the VSTS account.

#### 2. Loop for VSTS projects from step1 and [get all the git repos](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/vsts/git/repositories/list?view=vsts-rest-4.1) of each VSTS project

```
GET https://{accountName}.visualstudio.com/{project}/_apis/git/repositories?api-version=4.1
```

In the reponse of the REST API you can all the git repos for each project.

#### 3. Loop for git repos from step2 and get all the branches for each git repo

You can use [list refs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/vsts/git/refs/list?view=vsts-rest-4.1) REST API to get all the branches for each git repo:

```
GET https://{accountName}.visualstudio.com/{project}/_apis/git/repositories/{repositoryId}/refs?api-version=4.1
```

After executing all the loops, you will get all the branches for all git repos.

Answer (score 0):

With [Repositories - List](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/vsts/git/repositories/list?view=vsts-rest-4.1) you can get a list of all repos in your VSTS account.

Given that list you can iterate over all repos with [Refs - List](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/vsts/git/refs/list?view=vsts-rest-4.1) so that you should be able to get all refs and therefore information on branches.

A global API call to get all branches of all repos would also be difficult - branch names (refs) might be identical in different repos. One canoncial candidate for all repos is master branch.

Comment: Looks like it doesn't provide information on branches for all repositories. I need to pick a repository then it'll give me information about all the refs associated with that repository.

Comment: @Sameer Sorry only to have replied to the questionbelow your code. I've updated my answer, hope that will help you.